# Bind multiple keys to KeyDown event (Shift + * (Asterisk))

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, keydown

I am trying to bind multiple keys on a KeyDown event to change a bool variable, but I can't seem to figure out how to trigger the asterisk/star key (*) with the Left Shift key in the following code:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if (keyData == Keys.Multiply || keyData == (Keys.LShiftKey | Keys.OemQuotes))
    {
        Valgt = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer will not be keyboard layout invariant but this would do the trick on a US-EN keyboard.  It's not robust but can be adapted to your local layout.

```
if (keyData == Keys.Multiply || keyData == (Keys.Shift | Keys.D8))
{
    Valgt = true;
}
```

Alternatively you can use Control_KeyPress event

```
private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{            
    if (e.KeyChar == '*')
    {
        Valgt = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx, but I've already taken the US-keyboard into account as you've proposed. I'm looking for a universal asterisk (*) :-)

Comment: The other difference between my code and yours was the use of Keys.Shift as opposed to Keys.LShift.  If you break your debugger at the proposed line and evaluate the keyData you'll see that Keys.LShift evaluates to false where as Keys.Shift is true.  This solution handles the case of pressing the * key on the NumPad as well as Shift and the number 8.  What additional way of generating an asterisk were you searching for?

Comment: I was searching for a universal asterisk key detection.
I have a danish keyboard layout and my asterisk is not located on the "number 8" button, but instead on the "Single Quote/Double Quotes" button right next to the "Enter" button.

I was hoping for a universal solution to the asterisk key detection.

Comment: What about using the Control_KeyPress event instead of ProcessCmdKey.  KeyPressEventArgs contains a KeyChar property which you could check.  That will let you run your logic no matter what method was used to generate the *