# Detecting the Asterisk Key on KeyDown Event

Tags: c#, winforms, keyboard, intellisense, keyboard-events

Firstly I have seen the following answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/7731051/626442 and it is not quite sufficient for my needs.

I have written an editor which has basic intellisense capabilities (see [A New and Full Implementation of Generic Intellisense](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9556026/a-new-and-full-implementation-of-generic-intellisense) for an insight). I have implemented some basic SQL Server completion using this editor, but I keep getting intellisense popping up when I type the `*` key. I want to prevent this. Currently I do the following:

```
private void TextArea_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (!e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.Space || e.Shift)
        return;

    IntellisenseEngine.DisplayCompletion(this, (char)e.KeyValue);
}
```

I have recently redeveloped my control and I want to build on existing restrictions as to when and when not to show the insight window. A subset of what I want would be:

```
+------------------------------+-------------------+
¦   ¦ Modifier   ¦ Keys        ¦ Show Completion   ¦
¦---+------------+-------------¦-------------------¦
¦ 1 ¦ Shift      ¦ None        ¦ No                ¦
¦ 2 ¦ Shift      ¦ * (see note)¦ No                ¦
¦ 3 ¦ None       ¦ Space       ¦ No                ¦
¦ 4 ¦ Any        ¦ Arrow Keys  ¦ No                ¦
+------------------------------+-------------------+
```

et al. Note, the "*" `e.KeyCode` is `D8`, this is obviously not keyboard invariant and dependent on locale, hence is not sufficient.

Essentially I want my SQL intellisense to act like SQL Server Management Studio's (SQLMS), my questions are:

1. How can I detect the asterisk char key being pressed independent of keyboard locale.
2. What other key contions should I impose to make to suppress the pop-up of the intellisense window and to make it act like SQLMS?

I have tried using

```
private void TextArea_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if ((Control.ModifierKeys & Keys.Control) != Keys.Control && <Detect Space Bar> || 
         (Control.ModifierKeys & Keys.Shift) == Keys.Shift && e.KeyChar == '*')
    return;

    IntellisenseEngine.DisplayCompletion(this, (char)e.KeyValue);
}
```

But then I have the problem of detecting the space bar.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I find myself wondering why keypress is struggling with spaces? you may want to move it to the form keypress, and have it only do stuff if the text area is selected

Comment: If you refactor to strategy, you maybe able to determine a better course of actions.

Comment: @CallumLinington go on...

Comment: Well, looking at your `if` logic it is so hard to determine what you're trying to block out. It maybe more advisable to write either a Rules or Strategy pattern so that you can determine the routes of certain chars

Comment: You could also inject into certain strategies or rules the locale of the computer to determine finer grain control

Comment: Doing that sort of this would not be trivial. And I don't want to use a hammed to crack a walnut. The table I provided give a small list of the restriction I want to impose on the popup/insight window. I am happy with this collection of restrictions for now...

Comment: Fair point Hans, I will look at my event routing. If I can use the `TextChange` event before my underlying control consumes, this looks like the way I will go. I am still free to use `Control.ModifierKeys` using this method and have more freedom over how I handle entered characters. Again, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the modified code . Hope it will work

```
private void TextArea_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if ((Control.ModifierKeys & Keys.Contro) != Keys.Control && e.KeyChar == ' ' || 
         (Control.ModifierKeys & Keys.Shift) == Keys.Shift && e.KeyChar == '*')
    return;

    IntellisenseEngine.DisplayCompletion(this, (char)e.KeyValue);
}
```

Comment: It is the `<Detect Space Bar>` that I am having difficulty with.

Comment: Have u checked e.KeyCode == Keys.Space for detecting spacebar event?

Comment: Dude, `KeyPressEventArgs` does not have a `KeyCode` property. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Try `e.KeyChar == ' '`.

Comment: I actually should have tested that. `e.KeyChar == ' '` works okay.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
private void Principal_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    // if no special keys detected (May, Ctrl, etc)

    char keyChar = Convert.ToChar(e.KeyValue);
    if (keyChar == '\u0010')
    {
        // your code 
    }
}
```